# Objective-C associated objects leaking under ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-runtime

I have encountered with a strange `objc_setAssociatedObject` behavior under ARC. Consider the following code:

```
static char ASSOC_KEY;

@interface DeallocTester : NSObject
@end

@implementation DeallocTester
- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"DeallocTester deallocated");
    //objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ASSOC_KEY, nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSObject *test = [[DeallocTester alloc] init];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(test, &ASSOC_KEY, [[DeallocTester alloc] init],
                             OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
```

I'm creating an instance of `DeallocTester`, then I set another `DeallocTester` as an associated object for it, then both of them go out of scope.

I expect the `-dealloc` of the first object to be called, then the associated object to be deallocated too, but I see the `"DeallocTester deallocated"` message printed only once. If I uncomment the `objc_setAssociatedObject` line in `-dealloc`, the second object gets deallocated too.

The Objective-C reference states that associated objects are deallocated automatically upon object destruction. Is it a compiler/ARC/whatever issue or am I missing something?

**Update**

This sample code is actually working if you run it from a brand-new project. But I have two ARC-enabled projects where it doesn't. I'll do some investigation and provide a better sample.

**Update 2**

I've filled a [rdar://10636309, Associated objects leaking if NSZombie objects enabled in ARC-enabled project](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1472409)

Comment: If you are using LLVM3+ why are you using associated objects? You can just create iVars and properties in categories on the class instead.

Comment: @Abizern I'm going to add ivars to `NSObject`, AFAIR ivars can be added to a class extension category only, not to arbitrary one.

Comment: @Abizern Really? How do you create an ivar in a category?

Comment: @Abizern `@interface NSObject (MyCat) { int myivar; } @end` -> Ivars may not be placed in categories

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a source of a problem - I had `NSZombie` objects enabled in both my projects where this bug appears.

As far as I understand, when zombie objects are enabled, the normal instances are replaced with `NSZombie` upon deallocation, but all the associated objects are left alive! Beware of that behavior!

I've created a [rdar://10636309](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1472409)

**Update**: There's a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/2731698) by Cédric Luthi, and this issue appears to be fixed in iOS 6.

Comment: Heh, another good reason not to leave `NSZombie` enabled by default.

Comment: @jlehr And what are the other reasons? I always enable them in my projects, and haven't seen any drawbacks so far. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Leaving zombies enabled can mask a variety of problems, and of course it causes your app to leak tons of memory.

Comment: @jlehr Are you sure? Without zombies you cannot reliably find bugs with access to deallocated object until its wiped by another object, and a crash occurs. But you may be unlucky to not a crash, but call the absolutely unrelated object, so it's really more dangerous to live without zombies IMO). Yes, the memory can be a problem, but I haven't seen any real issues yet, seems they use some kind of memory saving or I'm just lucky enough :)

Comment: There's no reason to leave zombies enabled unless you're actively debugging memory management issues.

Comment: I noticed this when running the Leaks tool. I seem to recall the overridden dealloc was not even called on the object itself, but the ARC properties were getting zeroed out as if dealloc was called. Scary. +1 for having zombies enabled during the development/debug cycle by the way.

Comment: @iHunter In certain circumstances, NSZombies can silently allow crashing code to run.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works exactly as advertised under ARC. I rewrote your `dealloc` implementation to help make things a little more obvious.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"deallocating %@", self);
}
```

Here's the resulting log:

```
2012-01-03 06:49:39.754 ARC  Stuff[47819:10103] deallocating <DeallocTester: 0x6878800>
2012-01-03 06:49:39.756 ARC  Stuff[47819:10103] deallocating <DeallocTester: 0x688b630>
```

Are you sure you're compiling with ARC enabled?

Comment: Wow! What OS/XCode version are you using?

Comment: Me too. I'll now check again in fresh project.

Comment: I've checked my code with a fresh project, it's working! But I have two ARC-enabled larger projects, where the same code leaks! Magic. Looks like I should provide a better sample code.

Comment: Check your file-specific compiler flags and make sure you're not use -f-no-obj-arc for the .m file you put this in, maybe?